# $x(t)'=-3x(t)+2y(t), y'(t)=3x(t)-5y(t)+4z(t), z'(t)=3y(t)-4z(t),x(t)+y(t)+z(t)=1,x(0)=y(0)=z(0)=0$ solve for $y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
\begin{align*}
x'(t)&=-3x(t)+2y(t)\\
y'(t)&=3x(t)-5y(t)+4z(t)\\
z'(t)&=3y(t)-4z(t)\\
x(t)&+y(t)+z(t)=1,\forall t>0\\
&y(0)=1\\
&x(0)=z(0)=0
\end{align*}
$$

How could I solve $y$ for the above system? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know the Laplace transform?

Comment: @xpaul I don't know about that, I'm trying to do some algebra transformation to get the relationship between $x$ and $y$, or $y$ and $z$, then it could be easily solved

Comment: How can $x+y+z=1$ & then they are all initially zero ? Are your initial conditions consistent ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit $x,y,z$ are function about $t$, and for any $t$ greater than $0$, we have $x+y+z=1$, I am sorry, I do not make it clear.

Comment: Still stuck. All the values are initially zero ... all their derivatives will initially be zero & the functions will continue to be zero ? ... loose a constraint & I will give you a solution ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Yes you are right, I calculate the boundaries again, $y(0)=1,x(0)=z(0)=0$. I do not want the solution, any hint will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the equation $x+y+z=\color{red}{1}$ to eliminate $z$ so we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^{'} =-3x +2y \\
y^{'} =-x-9y -\color{red}{4}
\end{eqnarray*}
To get a general solution multiply by the second equation by $\lambda$ and ignore the  $ \color{red}{4}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^{'}  +\lambda y^{'} =(-3-\lambda)x +(2-9\lambda)y 
\end{eqnarray*}
We want the linear combination $x  +\lambda y$ to differentiate to a multiple of itself so we have the quadratic
 \begin{eqnarray*}
(-3-\lambda)\lambda =(2-9\lambda) 
\end{eqnarray*}
so $\lambda = 3 \pm \sqrt{7}$ ... which gives the general solution 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x +(3 + \sqrt{7})y=A e^{(-6 - \sqrt{7})t} \\
x +(3 - \sqrt{7})y=B e^{(-6 + \sqrt{7})t} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Is that enough of a hint ? ... more help on request.

Answer (score 1):

First notice that $x' + y' +z' = 0$ and you already have the sum to 1 constraint initially. So no need to worry about that anymore.

Now write it as a matrix equation

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z\\
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}-3&2&0\\3&-5&4\\0&3&-4\\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
\frac{d}{dt} \vec{p} = M \vec{p}
$$

If it was a scalar equation, that form would be $\frac{d}{dt} p = m*p$ with exponential solution. The same is still true but now you exponentiate the matrix $M$.

Suppose $O M O^{-1} = D$ is diagonal.

$$
e^{M t} \vec{p}(0) = e^{O^{-1} D O t } \vec{p}(0)\\
= O^{-1} e^{D t } O \vec{p}(0)\\
$$

so what you have left to do is compute $O$ and $D$.